# Ensuring Secure Data Remains in Memory

Tags: linux, security

On a Linux system, how would you structure a program (C/C++/Python/Java etc) to ensure that a piece of data remains in volatile memory and is never cached to disk or swap?

I'm specifically concerned with security applications where you want to ensure a manually entered password or cryptography key is forgotten and unrecoverable the moment the system loses power, but otherwise remains accessible.

Comment: I want to say "mlock" or similar? Although it might not be ideal (i.e. there might be a different, *better*, way to handle this for *security sensitive data*) .. if "mlock" does indeed fit the requirements, consider closing it as a duplicate as questions about it do exist.

Comment: Also, if you have FDE, when you lose power your swapfile stops being  readable to someone without creds to the machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [mlock(2)/munlock(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mlock.2.html)