# Data in Memory to minimise database reads?

Tags: go

How would you structure a program  in Golang to ensure that a piece of data remains in volatile memory and is never cached to disk or swap?

I am trying to implement bloom filter for usernames to minimise disk reads.

With reference to [Ensuring Secure Data Remains in Memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779947/ensuring-secure-data-remains-in-memory), I am looking for a solution in golang for a different purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can invoke the `mlock` syscall (and its kin) in Go, using the `syscall` package. See https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Mlock, for example.

That said, with the Go garbage collector that may not be 100% bullet-proof if you need cryptographic safety (e.g. ensure that keys never get to disk). You may want to consider libraries like [memguard](https://github.com/awnumar/memguard) in that case.